# Express send base-64 encoded png-image

Tags: node.js, express

In my node.js app I`m trying to respond with an image.

This image was saved before postgresql as text.

The text looks just like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPAAAAE
```

**But when I try to return it as an image:**

```
    res.type('image/png');
    res.send(image_string);
```

Or binary:

```
     res.send(image_string,'binary');
```

It shows a empty image-element: 
[image]

**What do I wrong?**Thanks

Answer (score 29):

I solved it by using a buffer:

```
const im = image_string.split(",")[1];

const img = Buffer.from(im, 'base64');

res.writeHead(200, {
   'Content-Type': 'image/png',
   'Content-Length': img.length
});

res.end(img);
```

Comment: Great answer, @John Smith. Just want to remind people to remove the data:image part, like so:
```
const buffer = new Buffer.from(base64Img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
```