# How to correctly return binary file (image) from lambda through API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Here is my lambda:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const hex = '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'

    const image = Buffer.from(hex, 'hex');

    const result = /* "data:image/png;base64," + */ image.toString('base64');

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png'
        },
        body: result,
        isBase64Encoded: true
  }


    return response;
};
```

Which is returned fine as *JSON*.

Next, in API Gateway, GET - Integration Response:

I set following through AWS Console:
`Content handling: Convert to binary (if needed)`

Header Mappings:
`Content-Type: 'image/png'`

Mapping Template:
`image/png`. Currently I use:

```
{
    "base64Image": $input.path('$.body')
}
```

Finally, in GET - Method Response:

Response Headers for 200: Name: `Content-Type`

Response Body for 200: Content-Type: `image/png` and Model: `Empty`

Binary Media Types is enabled with `image/png`.

Unfortunately,
Method Execution fails:

```
Mon Sep 23 09:52:37 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Content-Type":"image/png"},"body":"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 [TRUNCATED]
Mon Sep 23 09:52:37 UTC 2019 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform response
Mon Sep 23 09:52:37 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 500
```

What's wrong with my configuration? Did I miss something and where?

What I expect to get is `image/png` returned as binary file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three main steps required:

1. Lambda must return the image as base64 encoded string: `return image.toString('base64')`
2. In API Gateway > Method Execution > Integration Request > Mapping Templates - add `Content-Type: image/png`
3. In API Settings enable Binary Media Types and set it as `image/png`

Deploy API and in POSTMAN call the endpoint URL with headers: `Accept: image/png` and `Content-Type: image/png`.

That's it. This will return the image correctly as image!

If anyone needs more details, I've created a full tutorial that goes through each step:
https://medium.com/@iaforek/how-to-configure-binary-support-in-api-gateway-the-easy-and-working-way-ac2d68face36

What's important, you **don't** need to use `CONVERT_TO_BINARY` passthrough as other blog posts suggest.

Comment: I need help in returning a image as part of pdf from lambda. I have a java lambda deployed and it is rendering the data over xsl fo and generating the pdf and returning as json. But image which is there as base64 in xsl is not coming as part of pdf(base64 encoded) response.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Express and Serverless this worked for me:

Install the serverless-apigw-binary plugin:

`npm install --save-dev serverless-apigw-binary`

Be sure to have serverless-http installed:

`npm i serverless-http`

The answer here helped me to return a base-64 image in Express:

[Express send base-64 encoded png-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099000/express-send-base-64-encoded-png-image/34099141)

Here is my app.js file. Note that you must reference the binaries in module.exports.handler:

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res){
   var dataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";
   var dataUrlEdit = dataUrl.replace(/data:image\/png;base64,/, '');
   var img = Buffer.from(dataUrlEdit, 'base64');
   res.writeHead(200, {
     'Content-Type': 'image/png',
     'Content-Length': img.length
   });
   res.end(img);
})

module.exports.handler = serverless(app, {
    binary: ['image/png', 'image/gif']
  });
```

Here is my serverless.yml file:

```
service: your-app

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  app:
    handler: app.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'
```

Thanks to the answer from tomyates here:

https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http/issues/34

Comment: I had a problem with the browser not rendering the response image properly, so in `serverless.yml` I explicitly set `types: - 'image/jpeg'` instead of just `types: - '*/*'`, and that did the trick.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly with `netlify-lambda` using `expressjs`.

Comment: @robe007 Not everyone is using ExpressJS.

Comment: @iaforek Mine, is just a comment of what a _client_ was using.